# Adding VBO to an entity

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have created an entity. I have exposed it to views using `hook_views_data()`.
I can create a view for my data however when I try and add a field for `Bulk Operation` there is not a field listed for my entity type.

How do I expose my entity to VBO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `hook_views_data` implementation, you need to specify that the table is about an entity.

You need to define the entity first. I assume you have already defined your new entity using [`hook_entity_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7).

```
<?php 
function hook_entity_info() {
  return array(
    'my_table_item' => array(
      'label' => 'My new entity item',
      'base table' => 'my_table',
      'load hook' => 'my_table_item_load',
      'entity keys' => array(
        'id' => 'mtid',
        'label' => 'My new entity item',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
?>
```

Then, mention this new entity type in the `hook_views_data` implementation.

```
<?php
function hook_views_data() {
  $data = array()
  $data['my_table'] = array(
    'table' => array(
      'base' => array(
        'field' => 'mtid', // Primary field
        'title' => 'My new entity item',
        'help' => 'My Table',
      ),
      'entity type' => 'my_table_item', // <-- Important. Set the entity type here.
      'group' => 'My Table',
    ),
  );
}
?>
```

VBO will start to show actions that are type of `entity` in the available actions. 
To add new actions, implement hook_action_info.

```
<?php
function hook_action_info() {
  return array(
    'my_table_do_awesome_things' => array(
      'type' => 'my_table_item', // <-- New entity type here
      'label' => t('Do awesome things'),
      'behavior' => array('changes_property'), //<-- Triggers an entity save. 
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'vbo_configurable' => FALSE,
      'triggers' => array('any'),
    ),
  );
}
?>
```

I'm the first author (improved by the community later) of [VBO for Drupal 7 drupal.org documentation](https://drupal.org/node/2052067). Have a look at it as well, for a deeper explanation for `hook_action_info` and making them configurable at VBO level.

Comment: I have inherited this code. Are there other ways that you can declare entities? As hook_entity_info() does not seem to be there.

Comment: What do you mean `hook_entity_info does not seem to be there` ? Even the node entity is defined that way. http://is.gd/CjeS4h

Comment: ... and you obviously need to change "hook" in the function declarations to your own custom module's name and make further changes as necessary to match your custom tables.

Comment: The previous developer was using views to look at a table but was not making the table an entity.